# Calculate in sqlite and java

Tags: java, sqlite

How to calculate a value from a sqlite table with the previous value and add in a other table.

**example:**

```
value1 ---= value 2( calculate with previous value 1 and add with value 2 )

10.32 --- = 0
20.34 --- = 0 + 10.32
30.45 --- = 10.32 + 20.34
45.03 --- = 10.32 + 20.34 + 30.45
60.34 --- = 10.32 + 20.34 + 30.45 + 45.03
....
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `sum` the values, you should use it like so:

```
select sum(values) from table where id <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to do something like this:

```
Y0 = 0, X0 = 10.32, X1 = 20.34 ....
Y1 = Y0 + X0
Y2 = Y1 + X1
Y3 = Y2 + X2
.....
```

So basically Yn = Yn-1 + Xn-1, if n > 0.
If that is true, then select all the values 1 (X) and store them in a list. And recursively iterate through them doing addition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but how in java , I tried several ways, but it does not work ...

Comment: @mowglypro you will retrieve the list of all the X values (10.32, 20.34, ...) and create an empty yList and add the value 0 to it. then in a for loop 
    (int i = 1; i<= xList.size(); i++){ 
        yList.add(yList.get(i-1) + xList.get(i-1));
    }

this is one way to do it. Hopefully I did not do any typos.

Comment: @mowglypro Was the answer useful? If yes, please upvote it :) Thanks!

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply , it's ok , thank you !